# Does IBM DataWorks support integration between Object Storage and dashDB?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, dashdb

Does the IBM DataWorks Data Load API support integration between Object Storage and dashDB?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported. If you have an actual SoftLayer account then you can connect but connectivity to BlueMix Object Storage is not supported at this time and is considered for future releases.

**Note:** This question was answered on dw Answers by user Glen Walters. Here is the [link to the post](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/166630/dataworks-integration-between-object-storage-and-d.html).